# I try to get text align center with boostrap4 but it is not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

this is my website url:http://webdesignleren.com/ .
when you go to home page  under this page you see 4 images and texten under it .**onderhoud banden ** etc.
they all aligned left while I put text-align center.
I use bootstrap4 and when I go to the website:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/
I try to do the same code but it is not working.
this is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
<div class="home-content3-image1 w-100"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://webdesignleren.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/toyota-296x185-1.jpg" alt="Responsive image">
<div class=" row ">
<div class="image1-tekst1">Onderhoud</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="image-button1">Lees Verder</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

how I can get that **onderhoud** (text) to get to be aligned  center with bootsrap4? can you give me an example with this code of mijn above?
thanks
johan

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the snippet below. In fact, you do not need the `row` classes for your text under the image, because the image is `fluid` so it takes the full width of its container/wrapper.

Then, add the `text-center` class from bootstrap on your wrapper as I did. As is, your image will be centered, and all your content also. If you only want your title being centered, add the class `text-center` beside to `image1-tekst1`.

And, here is my suggestion : Have a look on [Bootstrap cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/) because I see you are trying to do the same thing as cards are already doing well ;)

```css
.home-content3-image1 {
    border: 2px solid hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    height: 18rem;
    margin-top: 3rem;
}
.image1-tekst1 {
    font-family: 'Ravi Prakash', cursive;
    font-size: 28px;
    /* text-align: center; */
     margin-top: -1rem;
}
.image-button1 {
    /* padding-left: 4rem; */
    margin-top: -0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
  <div class="home-content3-image1 w-100 text-center">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Responsive image">
    <p></p>
    <div class="image1-tekst1">Onderhoud</div>
    <div class="image-button1">Lees Verder</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, I would appreciate that you hit the solve button :). And if you want, I can add an example with bootstrap cards on your structure.